# Firefox does not recognize second keyboard input

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have two keyboards and the setting "use the same source for all windows". It works fine everywhere except with Firefox which does only recognize one of the keyboards. This happens since I updated to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

For clarification:

- I am using firefox 112.0.1-1
- I configured my keyboard with the GUI under "settings->keyboard->input sources" There I have two keyboard layouts, english and spanish. When I switch to spanish it works in every program except firefox, which responds as I was using the english layout.
- I am using the default Desktop environment (gnome-wayland?)

Comment: This is something you may want to file as a bug with the Firefox people.

Comment: @David: In general I would agree. However, That's not something I can reproduce on my Ubuntu 22.04, and filing a bug which can't be easily reproduced is not very meaningful. So at first hand I would suggest that the OP clarifies the question. Like do you with "keyboard" mean "keyboard layout" (as I assumed)? Exactly how did you set those layouts? Which Desktop environment are you using? With the answers to those questions, it's possible that people here can help to determine if there is a valid bug, or just a configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks, I added more details to the original question

Comment: Ok.. How do you switch between English and Spanish?

Comment: I change between keyboard layouts with super + tab

Comment: That shortcut is used by default for switching between applications, so possibly there is some conflict. Can you please change it back to the default **Super+Space** and see if it helps.

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment, I already use super + space.